# How can I allow orientation rotation while using manifest.json?

Tags: javascript, android, json, google-chrome, android-manifest

When I use a [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en) file within my web application and "add to home screen" on Chrome for Android, it loads in fullscreen mode (great) but also gets locked in portrait orientation (not great).

I want to load in fullscreen, but still allow for orientation rotation. Is this possible?

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-0-75x.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 0.75
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/home",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "natural" // I have tried natural, any, leaving this property out altogether without success
}
```

According to boyofgreen, you should be able to supply one of many [orientation options](http://www.thishereweb.com/understanding-the-manifest-for-web-app/).

Answer (score 14):

It turns out Chrome for Android was aggressively caching my `manifest.json` file. By manually clearing the cache "from the beginning of time" and setting the `orientation` property to a value of `any` I was able to get the desired behavior.

Worth noting, an orientation value of `natural` did not allow the screen to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my app (linkthethings.com). I had used the android add to home screen. As well as removing the manifest.json orientation value I also had to uninstall the app and install it again. Even using clear cache option described in [Clear Workbox cache of all content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376355/clear-workbox-cache-of-all-content) had no results.

Answer (score 0):

Same here
I had to uninstall and reinstall the PWA app.
On iOS it worked fine.
Just seems to be a problem with Android.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).